# On Primefaces, In a DialogFramework, how to intercept <p:dialog> CLOSE event and STOP it

Tags: jsf, primefaces, mouseevent

How to intercept "CLOSE" event before DialogFramework widget is completely closed to allow user to stop closing of dialog.

Using JQuery, I have tried to intercept "onclick" (or "mousedown") event on  tag that seems to represent the CLOSE button displayed in titlebar. I have tried same thing on  tag.

I have also tried to change "href=#" attribute of  tag but without success.

How can I resolve this problem ?

Below can you find html code generated by FSF/Primefaces

```
<div id="FormSession:j_idt272:0:CtcActionTable:0:j_idt281_dlg" 
     class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-hidden-container ui-draggable ui-resizable ui-overlay-visible" 
     role="dialog" 
     >
  <div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-top ui-draggable-handle">
    <span class="ui-dialog-title">CTC input: 82020</span>
      <a class="ui-dialog-titlebar-icon ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all" href="#" role="button">
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick"></span>
      </a>
  </div>
```

and below, you can find JQuery() instruction that I have tested.

```
 function onLoadDialog()
 {
 jQuery(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").attr("href", "?");

 jQuery(".ui-icon-closethick").click(function(e)    
     {
     alert("onclick");        
     return false;            
     });    

 jQuery(".ui-icon-closethick").click(function(e)    
     {
     alert("onclick");        
     return false;            
     });    

 jQuery(".ui-icon-closethick").mousedown(function(e)    
     {
     alert("mousedown");        
     return false;            
     });    

 jQuery(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").mousedown(function(e)
     {
     alert("mousedown");        
     return false;            
     });    

 jQuery(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").click(function(e)    
     {
     alert("onclick");        
     return false;            
     });
```

Comment: Download the source, inspect it and see if you can create a patch e.g. by overriding self function.  The source IS open.

Answer (score 1):

The code below is a solution.

```
var wgDialog 
    = jQuery(".ui-dialog.ui-overlay-visible",window.parent.document)
      .each
        (function(nIndex)
            {
            //var sId = $(this).attr('id');
            //var sNodeName = $(this).prop('nodeName');
            //var sClass = $(this).attr('class');
            var sWidgetName = $(this).attr('data-widgetvar');
            var wgDialog = window.parent.PF(sWidgetName);

            wgDialog.hide = function()
                {
                alert("OnHide()");    
                this.jq.hide();
                }
            });
```

First of all, on Primefaces, we don't have the possibility to give a widgetVarName when creating a DialogFramework. That is the main reason of why it is so difficult to obtain the widget.

You must know that PrimeFaces DialogFramework widget has 2 specifics class that others Dialog don't have: that is "ui-dialog" and ".ui-overlay-visible".

The first part of this code consists to search DialogFramework JQuery widget.

```
var wgDialog 
    = jQuery(".ui-dialog.ui-overlay-visible",window.parent.document)
      .each
        (function(nIndex)
```

Warning: DialogFramework widget is not defined in the same Browser Windows where the code is executed.
The code is executed in the Iframe Windows but the widget is defined in his parent Window !
This explain the second parameter of JQuery that is "window.parent.document".

I get the PrimeFaces widget name from 'data-widgetvar' attribute that PrimeFaces has put in  element that represent DialogFramework in xhtml file displayed on browser.

```
var sWidgetName = $(this).attr('data-widgetvar');
```

So, when I have this name, I can easely find the widget using PF() function.

```
var wgDialog = window.parent.PF(sWidgetName);
```

Now that I have the widget, I can "override" PrimeFaces.widget.Dialog.hide() function.

```
wgDialog.hide 
    = function()
        {
        alert("OnHide()");    
        this.jq.hide();
        }
```

I display a message to see that my code work and I call hide() method to effectively close the DialogFramework.

Thanks to kukeltje for his help.

Comment: Can you assign an id to the dialogFramework? By default the widgetVar value is identical to <id>_widget if I remember correctly. So you should be able to retrieve it then since you know the value. Good explanation added btw... Makes things clear for others